# Test if one OR an other substring is in a string, in a DRY way

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python, and try to grab the 'spirit' of it.
Simple question :
I want to test if either `'a'` or `'b'` are in a string `'xxxxxbxxxxx'`
I obvisouly could do

```
full_string = 'xxxxxbxxxxx'
if 'a' in full_string or 'b' in full_string :  
    print 'found'
```

but I feel there is a more simple way to do it "python style", without repeating `full_string` , what could be it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is as close as you can get:

```
full_string = 'xxxxxbxxxxx'
if any(s in full_string for s in ('a', 'b')):  
    print 'found'
```

Or you could use regular expressions:

```
import re

full_string = 'xxxxxbxxxxx'
if re.search('a|b', full_string):  
    print 'found'
```